# How can I put a background color on selected radio type input?

Tags: php, css, validation, input

I'm trying to figure this out searching all over the web how to highlight a selected or clicked option on iPay88 payment option.

Here's the scenario: I have 2 payment options, Bank Transfer and ipay88 gateway. There's no problem with bank transfer when selected. If I select ipay88 gateway, another payment methods will appear like thru paypal and another is Gcash. If you select one, nothing will happen (it won't display anything that you have selected it until you proceed with checkout) so the user won't have any idea what payment method under iPay88 he/she selected.

To address this, I want it to be highlighted or something for the user to see what payment method under ipay88 he/she select or click.

Let me share the codes below:

```
echo '<div class="ipay88_ph_gateway ipay88_opt_container" >';
            foreach ( $this->paymenttype_available_ph as $number ) {
                echo '<p  style="margin-bottom:5px;">';
                echo '<input type="radio" id="ipay88'.$this->types_mapping_ph['id'][ $number ].'"';
                echo 'name="ipay88_payment_type" value="'.$number.'">';
                echo '<label for="ipay88'.$this->types_mapping_ph['id'][ $number ].'">';
                    echo '<img alt="'.$this->paymenttype_options_ph[ $number ].'" src="'. WC_Compat_iPay88::force_https( WC_iPay88::plugin_url() ) .'/assets/images/'.$this->types_mapping_ph['image'][ $number ].'.'.$this->image_ext .'">';
                echo '</label>';
                echo '</p>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
```

Screenshots:
[payment method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dkwx.png)
[ipay88](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEhn0.png)

Comment: please check the link : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS to change the style of the form element,
The CSS rule would be:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked
```

then you can play with the CSS in order to get the result that you are looking for, something like this:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```